# PANDAS - Date showing error NaN instead of date when it works for one series, but not the other. both have the exact same method

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, date

```
finaldf = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Project_name', 'Vol_of_units', 'Total_units_sold','Balance_of_units', 'First_transacted_date', 'Last_transacted_date']) 
finaldf['Project_name']= first['project_name']
finaldf['First_transacted_date'] = first['sale_date']
finaldf['Last_transacted_date'] = last['sale_date'] #why display NaN? On top have sales date.
finaldf['Balance_of_units'] = remaining
finaldf['Vol_of_units'] = int(totalunits['no_of_units'])
finaldf['Total_units_sold'] = sold
```

#looking at finaldf.dtype gives me : both First_transacted_date and Last_transacted_date are objects[image]

Comment: Missing values means in `last` DataFrame is different index like in `finaldf`

Comment: for scalar use `finaldf['First_transacted_date'] = first['sale_date'].iat[0]`

Comment: hi @jezrael! thanks for answering :) could you elaborate  or clarify? so does it mean that the indexes in last is different from the finaldf dataframe?

Comment: @jezrael, thanks!! i managed to fix it by adding the iat[0] at the back of finaldf['Last_transacted_date'] = last['sale_date'].iat[0] and now it works. So why did the NaN error occur?

Comment: Reason is one element Series has different index like row for asigned data